# Why does my HTML code doesn't work inside my react-native application?

Tags: html, react-native, webview, paypal

I'm developing a small application and it should include a link to a PayPal donation site. Therefor I contacted PayPal and everything and finally got some HTML code (everything between (and including)  and  is what PayPal sent me). But somehow this code isn't working inside my app.

My code:

```
<View style = {{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}><HTMLView value={'<form action="https://www.paypal.com/donate" method="post" target="_top"> <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="(here's a value idk if I can share it)" /> <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/DE/i/btn/btn_donate_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" title="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" alt="Donate with PayPal button" /> <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/de_DE/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" /> </form>'}/></View>
```

What I've tried:

- just copied the code inside a .html file and opened it in a browser - that's working perfectly
- used some other HTML code instead (inside my app) - that's working too

What I saw inside the app:

- some white, not clickable, space

But why does this code not work inside the application? I would appreciate every help or alternatives to do this.